# blender 3d не показывает текстуры

Tags: blender, текстура

использую blender 2.8 на mac os.
создаю куб, в режиме редактирования делаю uv развертку, uv редактор ее показывает, нажимаю открыть изображение, выбираю. он его показывает в uv редакторе, но на объекте ни в одном режиме текстура не отображается (как это исправить ?)
 текстуры добавленные нодами в материалах отображаются, но это портит соотношение сторон и растягивает, думаю решить проблему используя uv (или можно исправить в материалах ?).

Answer (score 1):

Нажмите здесь (Viewport shading - color - texture):

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]